# Check If SQS and Lambda is encrypted using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs

Iam very new to AWS and I want to check whether SQS and Lambda is encrypted or not using boto3. I tried searching documentation but didnt find anything. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQS

Call `client.get_queue_attributes` and look at `KmsMasterKeyId` and `KmsDataKeyReusePeriodSeconds`

If those are not empty --> queue is encrypted

See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.get_queue_attributes